# changing slotMinutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I have display only calendars that initially come up with 20 minute slotMinutes.  I am trying to allow the user to change to 10 minute slotMinutes on the fly.

I have a button that triggers the following code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'slotMinutes', 10);
```

but I can't get the screen to redraw reflecting the new setting.  I have tried:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar("render")
$('#calendar').fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
```

I am using the agendaWeek view and would like it to redraw and remain in the same week.

I have poured over the docs.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried rerenderEvents ?

Answer (score 0):

Since that would require redrawing the whole calendar why not just remove the old #calendar instance from the view and reload full calendar with the new slotMinutes option? You can get the current view.start/view.end and view.name( http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/View_Object/) of the current view using the getView() function. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/getView/

Then after you've redrawn the calendar call 'goToDate' and use the 'start' date/time from above to change to the last used date.

It's dirty but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change options of fullcalendar on-the-fly. It is not supported right now. The only one way to do this anyway, is to rebuild the whole object.

A talk about this enhancement is [here](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293)

I made a dirty fork in [github](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/pull/25) for my needs, it could fits yours.

I've pasted the diff here (update your fullcalendar.js) :

```
function option(name, value) {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return options[name];
    }
    if(options[name] === value)
        return;
    options[name] = value;
    if (name == 'height' || name == 'contentHeight' || name == 'aspectRatio') {
        updateSize();
    }
    else {
        options.events = options.backupEvents;
        $(element).fullCalendar('destroy');
        $(element).fullCalendar(options);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Then how would you implement this? Calling fullcalendar with new options seems to not work or trigger the above code.

Comment: Oh I see: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'slotMinutes', 10);

Comment: Unfortunately this wipes out the events option.